# Extra Character Display in Terminal Command Prompt

Tags: macos, bash, terminal.app, .bash-profile

I started to see an extra bracket on my Mac Terminal

I thought it is because of my `.bash_profile` that I might have broke when I modified it.

But `NO`. I comment the whole file out and I still see that

`[` - at the beginning of my prompt

`]` - at the end of my prompt

[image]

---

## Question

**How would one go about and debug this ?**

---

I'm opening to any suggestions at this moment.

Any hints / suggestions / helps on this be will  be much appreciated !

Comment: and you didn't think to show us your $PS1 variable?

Comment: I commented out my entire `.bash_profile` , I'm not sure how to show it to you. Should I include my commented out .bash_profile ? Do you think it is necessary ?

Comment: You can show us with `echo "${PS1}"` or optionally with literal double-quotes: `echo "\"${PS1}\""

Comment: If I comment out my **.bash_profile**, Run `echo "${PS1}"` return 
`\h:\W \u\$ `

Comment: If I don't comment out my **.bash_profile**, Run `echo "${PS1}"` return 
`──\[\033[1;37m\][\[\033[0;32m\]\w\[\033[1;37m\]]\n└── \[\033[1;37m\]`

Comment: it is caused by the PS1 / PS2 variable.  Changing that will remove the []s.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the marks on the outside of the terminal.  Shown here:

[image]

That bracket is a feature of Terminal, and not realated to your prompt.  The solution is to *Hide Marks*, go to **View -> Hide Marks** and they will no longer appear.

[image]

Comment: That marks was killing me! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

What extra character? If you mean the tilde "~" then that is just an indication that you are somewhere in you home directory tree. Tilde is the standard *nix abbreviation for your "home" directory.

Comment: I highlight it with a red box in my picture in my post. It's not ~. It's `[` and `]`